# Need to append SameSite=None; Secure to a cookie in Tomcat

Tags: windows, url-rewriting, session-cookies, tomcat8, samesite

I have an install of Tomcat 8.0.30 that is hosted on a Windows Server VM.  I am having an issue with the new Chrome 80 update that is causing errors due to the new requirement for SameSite=None and Secure to be passed in cookies.

Because of the older version of Tomcat, I can not use the Cookie Processor, because it ommits the SameSite attribute.

I was hoping I could address this with a url rewrite rule like below, but it fails with it.
Any idea what is wrong with my RewriteRule?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} JSESSIONID [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ ($1$2; SameSite=None; Secure)
```

Comment: Since the RewriteRule stuff is in Apache HTTPd, you are really asking how you would modify cookie attributes to have "SameSite=None; Secure" via Apache configuration.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104573/how-to-set-samesite-cookie-attribute-using-apache-configuration